# where to copy ST_geometry.so on Linux server?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, esri-geodatabase, spatial-database, ubuntu

I run PostgreSQL 9.2 on an Ubuntu server. Through ArcCatalog 10.1 I can connect to the database (although it is empty right now). When trying to "Enable Enterprise Geodatabase" I get the following error:

```
You must copy the latest ST_GEOMETRY and dependent libraries to the PostgreSQL software location. Refer to the ArcGIS help topics for more details.
```

I've copied st_geometry.so from the ArcGIS install location on my Windows machine to the Ubuntu server. I placed the file in /var/lib/pgsql/9.2 .

Still, I get the same error message. Is there something else I have to do in order to have the ST_GEOMETRY library "installed"?

Comment: If PostgreSQL is installed on a Linux server, log in to the server as the root user and place the st_geometry.so file in the /usr/lib64/pgsql  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//019v0000000r000000

Answer (score 2):

The location of the lib directory on Linux can vary depending on how you installed PostgreSQL. To determine the correct location for your PostgreSQL installation, execute pg_config as the postgres user. The value that is returned for PKGLIBDIR is the lib directory where you need to place the st_geometry library. Log in as the root user to copy the file to the lib location.

As per the Doc